# Hide form while loading data

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS app I want to hide some page elements (sometimes all of them) until all async data is loaded.

Any suggestions on how to solve that when I have several data requests in the same controller?

I also would like to combine it with http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress and find a solution with a service that listens to the status of dataLoaded (or whatever solution is best) that I can use in all different controllers of the app.

**controller.js**

```
$scope.dataLoaded = false;

dataFactory.getProduct(accessToken, storeId).then(function (response) {
    $scope.formData = response.data;
    $scope.dataLoaded = true;
}, function (error) {
    console.log('Error: dataFactory.getProduct');
});

dataFactory.getBrand().then(function (response) {
    $scope.brandData = response.data;
    $scope.dataLoaded = true;
}, function (error) {
    console.log('Error: dataFactory.getBrand');
});
```

**service.js**

```
app.factory("dataFactory", function ($http) {
var factory = {};

factory.getProducts = function (accessToken, storeId) {
    return $http.get('data/getProducts.aspx?accessToken=' + accessToken + '&storeId=' + storeId)
};

factory.getProduct = function (accessToken, storeId, productId) {
    return $http.get('data/getProduct.aspx?accessToken=' + accessToken + '&storeId=' + storeId + '&productId=' + productId)
};

factory.getBrand = function (accessToken, storeId) {
    return $http.get('data/getBrand.aspx?accessToken=' + accessToken + '&storeId=' + storeId)
};

return factory;
```

});

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is to resolve that function using your route provider with a combination of ng-cloak class that works like a charm, and also you can hide and show a "loader image" while you are switching routes.

let's say you have this service in your app:

```
app.factory("greetingService", function($q, $timeout){
   return {
       getGreeting: function(){
           var deferred = $q.defer();
           $timeout(function(){
               deferred.resolve("Allo!");
           },2000);
           return deferred.promise;
       }
   }
});
```

setting up the "resolve" function

```
.when("/anyroute", {
    templateUrl: "anyview.html",
    controller: "anyController",
    resolve: {
        greeting: function(greetingService){
            return greetingService.getGreeting();
        }
    }
})
```

in your controller:

```
app.controller("anyController", function ($scope, greeting) {
    $scope.greeting = greeting;
});
```

you can inject your "resolved" dependency right before your controller, that way you'll have the initial data when the controller loads.

for showing and hiding a loader you can do a directive like

```
angular.module('app').directive('loaderBar', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="showloader"><img src="loader.gif" alt="loading..." /></div>',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var namedListener = $rootScope.$$listeners['$stateChangeStart'];
            if (namedListener === null || namedListener === undefined) {
                $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
                    element.addClass('animatedLoader');
                });
                $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
                  element.removeClass('animatedLoader');
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

and don't forget to use ng-cloak class to hide the contents while loading at the top of each view, that will work like a charm!

Comment: Thanks! Right now I am using ng-cloak on the <form> but it only hides the form until the HTML is loaded, but it still misses the form data. So, just for that part, shouldn't ng-cloak be working?

Comment: Well that's the reason you need to load your data in the resolve function

Comment: Sorry, but I am new to AngularJS. I don't understand how to implement it in my code. My data reuqests are resolved in the controller, so is your solution working for me then?

Comment: you just need to move the resource that loads the data in the beginning to your  route provider and put it on the resolve method, you can easily replace the promise on the greeting service (var deferred = $q.defer();) with any resource you have

Comment: take a look at this plunker as an example http://plnkr.co/edit/GudLBQP0INk6CVF04gWr?p=info